# On Button Click Event my Page is not Redirect to admin.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Retrive values from admin table and then i store in String variable and finally i compare values my code is not redirect to another page

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String uname = (String)txtuser.Text;
        String upass = (String)txtp.Text;
        String cuser = "";
        String cpass = "";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMSS"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        String query = "select username,password from admin where username=@username";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", uname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", upass);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            cuser = rdr["username"].ToString();
            cpass = rdr["password"].ToString();
        }


        if (cuser==uname && cpass==upass)
        {
            Session["user"] = cuser;
            Response.Redirect("admin.aspx",true);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: are you sure your if condition is true?

Comment: ya logically its true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check following code lines?

```
String uname = (String)txtuser.Text;
```

1. (string) implicit cast is not necessary: Text property is already a string.

   conn.Open();
2. missing `conn.Close();` it's better to add also `try/catch`

   String query = "select username,password from admin where username=@username";

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", upass);
3. why don't you check also password in the query?

   cuser = rdr["username"].ToString();
4. It means null value not allowed

   if (cuser==uname && cpass==upass)
5. Problem with case sensitive/trim. In debug do you arrive on Response.Redirect?

   Response.Redirect("admin.aspx",true);
6. Maybe `~/admin.aspx`

Comment: String uname = (String)txtuser.Text i know implicit cast is not necessary in this line of code,i already check all points you written but it doesn't works

Comment: Use debug and tell us values for: cuser, uname, cpass, upass

Comment: cuser=gaurav,uname=gaurav,cpass=12345678,upass=12345678

Comment: Sure? Any space? Try to trim.

Comment: sorry i noticed my cuser="gaurav                                               " with space and cpass is also with space cpass="12345678        "

Comment: cuser.Trim() and cpass.Trim()

Answer (score 0):

try to change your condition to below

```
if (cuser.ToLower() == uname.ToLower() && cpass.ToLower() == upass.ToLower())
```